# Understanding redirection using HTTP_HOST

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently going through a tutorial on redirects and have become slightly confused.
The following is supposed to redirect all requests to the current domain to a new domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old_domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new_domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

However what is the purpose of `HTTP_HOST`? What does it contain? To me `HTTP_HOST` contains the current hostname? (`old_domain.com`) therefore my understanding of the above rule is that it is testing for a string containing the old domain followed by the old domain again? `old_domain.com/old_domain.com`

Shouldn't it be?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new_domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

As another example to aid understanding how would you redirect a request to `mysite.com` (followed by nothing else, so essentially a request to the index page) to `mysite2.com` using `HTTP_HOST`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is checking the supplied host `%{HTTP_HOST}` against the old one. So if a request comes into the server with the host "old_domain.com" then the next rule should be run. If the host is anything else, even www.old_domain.com, then the next rule will be skipped.

To say it another way, `%{HTTP_HOST}` is what the user passes to the server. That condition checks what the user supplied again what you've written rules for.